# Why does the map size returns 0

Tags: c++

```
  using namespace std;

  class A {
      public:
         A() {}
         ~A() {}

         map<int, string*>& getMap() {
             return mapStr;
         }

         void setMap(const map<int,string*> m) {
             mapStr = m;
         }

      private:
          map <int, string*> mapStr;
  };


  class B {

      public:
      A getA() {
          return a;
      }
      private:
      A a;

  };

  int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {

      map<int, string*> mm;
      mm.insert(std::make_pair(1, new string("abc")));
      mm.insert(std::make_pair(2, new string("def")));

      B b;
      b.getA().setMap(mm);
      cout << "Size " << b.getA().getMap().size() << std::endl;
      return 0;
  }
```

Output:
      Size 0

Any ideas as to why does this return the map size to be 0 and what needs to be done to be fixed

Comment: did u try writing size before assigning mm to the one contained in A?

Comment: In addition to `getA` returning a reference, the argument to setMap should be passed by reference for efficiency's sake: `void setMap(const map<int,string*>& m)`. Otherwise, setMap will get a temporary that's a copy of the argument.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `getA` method is returning a temporary *copy* of `a`, so your call to `setMap` is modifying that copy, not the original. One way to fix this would be to have `getA` return a reference or pointer to `a`

Answer (score 0):

Each call to getA() is creating and returning a new temporary object.

So the first call:

```
b.getA().setMap(mm);
```

Creates an A object adds mm into it.
This then goes out of scope and destroys the map.

This line:

```
cout << "Size " << b.getA().getMap().size() << std::endl;
```

Creates a completely new A object with its own empty map.
As it is a new object the size of the map is zero.
Once this goes out of scope it is again destroyed.

I think what you meant to do is:

```
class B
{ 
    A& getA()         // Notice the & just after the A 
    {                 // rather than return an object by value
        return a;     // you want to return a reference to the object inside
    }                 // your B object.
    private:
        A a;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a copy of an A, not the A object you're modifying.  Try out this code to understand the difference:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  map<int, string*> mm;
  mm.insert(std::make_pair(1, new string("abc")));
  mm.insert(std::make_pair(2, new string("def")));

  B b;
  A a = b.getA();
  B bb;
  bb.getA().setMap(mm);
  a.setMap(mm);

  cout << "A Size " << a.getMap().size() << std::endl;
  cout << "BA Size " << bb.getA().getMap().size() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

B::getA() is returning an object by value.  Si when you call A::setMap() you are setting the map of the temporary object.

Change the signature of getA() to:

```
A &getA();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method getA currently returns a copy, instead of a reference to, the a member.  Instead, you want to return A& from getA.  This will allow you to return a reference to your member variable instead of a copy of it.